# How to resize iAd in app?

Tags: ios, xcode, iad, ads

I don't want a banner and want to create my own size for iAd. Preferably, a square. Is there any possible way to shape iAd into a square and still put it in my app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS7 Auto Layout, View Resize and iAds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297209/ios7-auto-layout-view-resize-and-iads)

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. All the ads iAd serves are created for specific dimensions and would look pretty bad if you made them square. I would also guess that Apple would reject your app for using iAd incorrectly.

You may be able to find a different mobile ad company that does allow square ads. There are plenty of other companies to choose from.

If you don't want to do a banner, you should look into interstitials or check out Kiip and their ad format. You'll generally find much higher ecpms with interstitials and kiip anyway.

Comment: Do you know any mobile ad company that does so?

Comment: I looked around, but didn't find any that fit what you're looking for. That's not to say it doesn't exist, there are a ton of mobile ad distributors.